# Equivalent ways to read Implication form

Tags: logic

I have learn that there are so much ways to read ***Implication*** and I've been given about 4 ways for now. Implies that P -> Q;

- If P then Q
- P only if Q
- P is sufficient for Q
- Q whenever P

I was told that there are 11 more or so ways to read them. Can someone give the rest of them?
For now, at least I have found other 3 of them.

- Q, if P
- P implies Q
- Only if Q is P

Comment: "$Q$ is necessary for $P$."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Hammack's *Book of Proof*:

\begin{align}
    \left. \begin{array}{l}
        \text{If P, then Q.} \\
        \text{Q if P.} \\
\text{Q whenever P.} \\
\text{Q, provided that P.} \\
\text{Whenever P, then also Q.} \\
\text{P is a sufficient condition for Q.}\\
\text{For Q, it is sufficient that P.}\\
\text{Q is a necessary condition for P.}\\
\text{For P, it is necessary that Q.}\\
\text{P only if Q.}\\
    \end{array}\right\} P\Longrightarrow Q
\end{align}